# Tomcat 127.0.0.1 works, but localhost or externalIP fail

Tags: java, ajax, linux, tomcat

Hi i have a servlet with ajax call like:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyApplication/MyServlet",
        data: {user:name, surname:surname},
        type:"GET",
        crossDomain: true,
         contentType: 'text/plain',
        success: function(data,stato){
            alert("dati: " + data + "\n stato: " + stato);
            $("#pannello").empty().append(data);
        },
        error: function(richiesta, stato, errori){
            alert("errore:" + stato);

        },

    });
```

When i try to use it use `127.0.0.1:8080/MyApplication` works good, but doesn't work `localhost:8080/MyApplication` or `192.168.0.5:8080/MyApplication`.
I changed `/etc/hosts` file using
 `127.0.0.1 localhost` and I added in my `/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/server.xml`

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
address="0.0.0.0"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

But the problem isn't solved. Some solution?

Comment: How about `ping localhost` or `ping 192.168.0.5`? Do these work?